# KFramework: Issues with `#isConcrete` and function global configuration lookup

Tags: kframework

I am trying to compile a module using the syntax for doing a global environment lookup in a function rule.
When I try to compile my module using the Java backend, I get the error `Conversion of KAs unsupported on Java backend!` `(_0,``(I),_1) #as #Configuration`, presumably related to the desugaring (though the `pending-documentation` states "This is completely desugared by the K frontend and does not require any special support in the backend."...but as it is pending I understand it's probably not always entirely accurate).

So I tried the Haskell backend. This also gives me an error about using `#isConcrete`, which I noticed is documented as not being supported in the Haskell backend...but I wasn't using `#isConcrete`. However, I discovered that if I remove the cell from my configuration which uses `stdout`, then I no longer get this error.

Is it possible to both use this syntax **and** have `stdout`? Ideally I could keep using the Java backend, because that's where I seem to run into the fewest issues.

Below is a simple example that produces the error:

```
module TEST-SYNTAX
    imports DOMAINS-SYNTAX
    syntax Prog ::= run(Int)
endmodule

module TEST
    imports TEST-SYNTAX
    imports DOMAINS

    syntax KResult

    configuration
        <k> $PGM:Prog </k>
        <bar> 6 </bar>
        <log stream="stdout"> .List </log>

    syntax Int ::= foo(Int) [function]

    rule [[ foo(0) => I ]]
         <bar> I </bar>

    rule run(I) => foo(I)
endmodule
```

with the program being simply `run(0)`.

Comment: this looks like a bug to me (in the way domains.k is fed to the Haskell backend), I've filed a bug report: https://github.com/kframework/k/issues/1436. We likely won't get to it until late next week or early the week after.

Comment: If you can get by without using `stdout` for now, I would recommend using the Haskell backend. We are working on deprecating the Java backend, and it has several known limitations/soundness issues.

Comment: If you're doing concrete execution instead (you don't need to use the symbolic executor), then use the LLVM backend, and you should be able to side-step all these issues.

Comment: This is addressed by this PR: https://github.com/kframework/k/pull/1456